# Change the values ​of an array based on proximity of quantile numbers

Tags: python

There are numerical array as input: `1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 123, 123, 154, 243, 213, 1231241237, 1231241236, 1231241239`

What i want to see  on the output:  `1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ,1 ,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 154, 154, 154, 154, 154, 1231241239, 1231241239, 1231241239`

There are code in R which do what i want. I neet translate this one into python:

```r
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67766337/change-the-values-of-a-vector-based-on-proximity-of-quantile-numbers
vector <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 123, 123, 154, 243, 213, 1231241237, 1231241236, 1231241239)
q <- quantile(vector, probs = c(0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1)) %>% unname()
q[sapply(vector, function(x) which.min(abs(x - q)))]
# 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ,1 ,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 154, 154, 154, 154, 154, 1231241239, 1231241239, 1231241239
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
data = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 123, 123, 154, 243, 213, 1231241237, 1231241236, 1231241239])
        
quantiles = np.quantile(data, [0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1])
        
print((quantiles[abs(data[None, :] - quantiles[:, None]).argmin(axis=0)]).tolist())
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).